# How to unittest jquery elements within angularjs code

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

```
var FormID = $('form').attr('id');


if ($('#' + FormID).valid()) { // getting error in this line within my login controller
```

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'form' of undefined
>               at a.extend.valid (D:/Sprint-11/omnichannel-prodsupp-workingrepo-11/src/vendors/jquery-validation/js/jquery.validate.min.js:4:1217)

Comment: are there multiple forms to validate?

Answer (score 0):

> One thing you should remark before `$('form').valid()` method call,
>   Checks whether the selected form is valid or whether all selected
>   elements are valid. validate() needs to be called on the form before
>   checking it using this method.

[.valid()](http://jqueryvalidation.org/valid) method description here you get idea about it.

[validate()](http://jqueryvalidation.org/validate) needs to be called on the form before checking `.valid()` Method.

**Example**

```
jQuery.validator.setDefaults({
  debug: true,
  success: "valid"
});
var form = $("#myform");
form.validate();
$("button").click(function() {
  alert( "Valid : " + form.valid());
});
```